# Trouble printing a 2D char array in C while using fscanf

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 5

void readBoard (FILE *fp, char table[N][N], int n){
  int i, err, j, counter = 0;
  char c;
  int row = 0, col = 0, ch = 0;

  while((err = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c)) == 1){

    if (c!= ' ' && (c == 'o' || c == 'M' || c == '.')){
      ch++;
      counter++;

      if (counter == 5){
       counter = 0;
        row++;
      }

    }

     if( c != ' ' && c != 'M' &&  c != 'o' && c!= '.' && c != '\n'){
      printf("Error. File is not correct. \n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

  }

  col = ch/row;

 if (col != N || row != N){
    printf("Error. Incorrect data in file. \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }


  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  while((err = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c)) == 1){

    if( c!= ' ' &&  (c == 'o' || c == 'M' || c == '.')){

      table[i][j] = c;
      j++;

     if(j == N-1){
       j = 0;
       i++;
    }

   }

  }

}



void displayBoard (char table[N][N]){

  int r = 0;
  int c = 0;
  char ch;


for(r = 0; r<N; r++){
  for(c = 0; c<N; c++){
    printf("%c ", table[r][c]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}
int main(char argc, char *argv[]){

 char game[N][N];
 char err, c;

 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

 if(fp == NULL){
   printf("File not found.");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 readBoard(fp, game, N);
 displayBoard(game);


 return 0;
```

}

The first function reads characters from a file checks if they are correct and stores them into a 2D array.
The second array is used to print the array. Instead of printing the array it prints this:

```
� � � 2
   0

@    

    p
```

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: `if(j == N-1){` -> `j == N`. And don't use _magic numbers_.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Why are you not using the `letters[]` you defined in `displayBoard()`?

Comment: the `letters[]` will be used later

Comment: That is why you are asked for a *minimal* example, to avoid irrelevant questions.

Comment: Please check `argc` before dereferencing `argv[1]`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop will read all contents from where the file pointer is when `readBoard()` is called. You will have to restore the file pointer's position before the second loop.

Try adding

```
long origPtr = ftell(fp);
```

before the first `while((err = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c)) == 1){` and

```
fseek(fp, origPtr, SEEK_SET);
```

before the second `while((err = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c)) == 1){`.

Comment: There is error about being undeclared